# How can I get the thumbnail that nautilus uses for a given file?

Tags: c, linux, thumbnails, gnome

Nautilus shows me a thumbnail of a file, if its an image it will show me a preview, if its a video it will show a frame from the video, if its a document it will show me the application icon.

How can I access the image?

I see they are cached in `~/.thumbnail/` however they are all given unique names.

Answer (score 13):

> the thumbnail filename is an md5 of the filename. However the filename
>   is the absolute URI to the image (without a newline).
>
> So you need to do:
>
> `echo -n 'file:///home/yuzem/pics/foo.jpg' | md5sum`
>
> And if it has spaces, you need to convert them to '%20', ex for "foo bar.jpg"
>
> `echo -n 'file:///home/yuzem/pics/foo%20bar.jpg' | md5sum`

Found at [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-666742.html). See also the [Thumbnail Managing Standard](http://specifications.freedesktop.org/thumbnail-spec/thumbnail-spec-latest.html) document, linked from the [freedesktop.org wiki](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Specifications/).

Comment: When the thumbnail is not there, what's the mechanism to force the generation?

Comment: **Not only spaces have to be encoded!** E.g. `[` and `]` need to become `%5B` and `%5D`. See standard [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). You probably want to use a library/API/framework for this. Search for "uri encode". (there's [this built-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) for JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

Simple Python tool to calculate the thumbnail path. Written by [Raja](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/users/4172172/), shared as an [ActiveState code recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576942-locate-thumbnail-file/). Note, however, that this code does not escape filenames with spaces or special characters; which means this code does not work for all filenames.

```
"""Get the thumbnail stored on the system.
Should work on any linux system following the desktop standards"""

import hashlib
import os

def get_thumbnailfile(filename):
    """Given the filename for an image, return the path to the thumbnail file.
    Returns None if there is no thumbnail file.
    """
    # Generate the md5 hash of the file uri
    file_hash = hashlib.md5('file://'+filename).hexdigest()

    # the thumbnail file is stored in the ~/.thumbnails/normal folder
    # it is a png file and name is the md5 hash calculated earlier
    tb_filename = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~/.thumbnails/normal'),
                               file_hash) + '.png'

    if os.path.exists(tb_filename):
        return tb_filename
    else:
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Usage:  get_thumbnail.py filename')
        sys.exit(0)

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    tb_filename = get_thumbnailfile(filename)

    if tb_filename:
        print('Thumbnail for file %s is located at %s' %(filename, tb_filename))
    else:
        print('No thumbnail found')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need to access the thumbnail programatically. You want to use the [Gio library](http://developer.gnome.org/platform-overview/stable/gio).

I haven't been able to find a way to check for the thumbnail and, if it doesn't exist, go for the application icon, so you need to do it in two steps. Here you have a sample (sorry, Python. I'm not fluent in C):

```
import gio
import gtk

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
window.show()
hbox = gtk.HBox()
hbox.show()  
window.add(hbox)

f = gio.File(path='/home/whatever/you/want.jpg')
info = f.query_info('*')

# We check if there's a thumbnail for our file
preview = info.get_attribute_byte_string ("thumbnail::path")

image = None
if preview:
    image = gtk.image_new_from_file (preview)
else:
    # If there's no thumbnail, we check get_icon, who checks the
    # file's mimetype, and returns the correct stock icon.
    icon = info.get_icon()
    image = gtk.image_new_from_gicon (icon, gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU)

hbox.add (image)

window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```