# Trigger thumbnail generation for a given file in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thumbnails

After googling and searching I found out that for a particular file `/home/user/example file.doc` the corresponding thumbnail is in `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/thumbnails/normal/hash.png`, where `hash=md5("file:///home/user/example%20file.doc")`

(I found that in a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112602/how-can-i-get-the-thumbnail-that-nautilus-uses-for-a-given-file) and the Thumbnail Managing Standard)

But when the thumbnail is not generated yet, how do I trigger the generation?

I've tried exploring d-bus with d-feet, but didn't spot a relevant call.

Comment: That would depend on what desktop environment and/or file indexer you are using: some might have "triggers" for it, others might have library functions, and sometimes you might want to create them yourself based on the standard you mention (e.g. when it's not a common file format)

Answer (score 0):

I started to dig into source code and found that [Tumbler](https://git.xfce.org/xfce/tumbler/tree/README) does this.